# How do I select multiple bones in pose mode using python?

Tags: python, rigging

I cant seem to find any documentation on pose mode bone selection.

Comment: `bpy.data.armatures[X].bones[X].select = True`

Comment: I tried this and it says 

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\METAHUMAN_UV\_Repose\Repose_Step_25.blend\Text", line 3, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[id, lib]: is only valid for bpy.data collections, not Armature'

Comment: What exactly is the code you ran?

Comment: Sorry, that was a blank script, this is my issue at line 540

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\Desktop\METAHUMAN_UV\_Repose\Repose_Step_25.blend\Text", line 540, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[id, lib]: is only valid for bpy.data collections, not Armature'

I used this line to select both foot bones

bpy.data.armatures["Root"].bones["foot_l","foot_r"].select = True

Comment: You can't do `bones["foot_l","foot_r"]`. If there are multiple bones you want to select, you need to loop through and select them one by one.

Comment: Nevermind I got it using the correct loop. Thank you so much